# Installing MySQL on CentOS 7 using Dockerfile failing

Tags: mysql, docker, centos

I am trying to setup MySQL using a Dockerfile which uses CentOS 7 .. I know I should be using a seperate container for MySQL, but due to limitations I can't, so now I have to install it using the Dockerfile and i am running into some issues.

I have looked a few different places and got some ideas, and put the following together;

```
FROM centos:7

RUN yum -y update
RUN yum -y install \
    httpd \
    mariadb-server \
    mariadb \
    && rm -rf /var/cache/yum/* \
    && yum clean all

ENV DB_USER testuser
ENV DB_PASSWORD testpass
ENV DB_NAME testdb

RUN /usr/bin/mysqld  && sleep 5 && \
    mysql -uroot -e "CREATE USER '${DB_USER}'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '${DB_PASSWORD}'" && \
    mysql -uroot -e "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO '${DB_USER}'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION" &&\
    mysql -uroot -e "CREATE DATABASE ${DB_NAME}"

EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 3306

CMD ["/usr/sbin/httpd","-D","FOREGROUND"]
```

This seems to be for abother distro as /usr/bin/mysqld doesnt actually exist on Centos7 and I can find no other way to set things up manually ... I usually use the `mysql_secure_installation` command when setting up a VM, but as im doing this through a `Dockerfile` i can't as it requires input from the user.

I was wondering if anybody has manually setup MySQL using a Dockerfile on Centos and has some tips to get this going.

The error i keep coming up against when trying to use Mysql in the container is;

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'
```

Comment: A container only runs one process; the image doesn't persist running processes.  This setup will be much easier to run and debug (and you can reuse the Docker Hub `mysql` image) if you do it in two separate containers.

Comment: 2 seperate centos7 containers?

Comment: @DavidMaze .. That actually makes a lot of sense ... I didnt think of that

Comment: @CodeSauce How did you get this working?